# How do I make an Excel formula return Yes or No based on conditions AND nothing when blank

Tags: excel-formula

After looking online for a few hours, I haven't been able to solve this formula problem.

Basically, if F13 is blank, then I want the answer cell to reflect either 0 or TRUE because I'm only counting "yes" or "no" responses. Here's the formula I'm using:

=IF(ISBLANK(F13),(F13<=H13,"Yes", "No")

Please let me know how to fix this. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please explain you question with examples of data and what is you desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not super clear, but just guessing from your formula you probably need multiple `IF` statements. Something like

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F13), "0",
IF(F13<=H13, "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was it! I didn't know I could do two "IF" statements in one formula.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you found that it answered you question, feel free to click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted